Spring 6 OAuth 2.0 - No Refresh Token | PKCE Public Client

Edit
I found more about this topic here on StackOverflow:
PKCE Public Client - No Refresh Token
They said, there isn't any refresh token aviable for public pkce clients.
So I have to redirect the user time for time to the auth server to generate new auth-code to generate new access_token.

I got stuck with the OAuth 2.0 Server in Spring 6 Spring Boot 3.
I build an AuthServer and an ResourceServer.
With my JS-Client I can Log in, get an auth-code, then I can exchange this code for the access-token and here begins the dilema.
I get an json-obj with:
access_token
scope
id_token
token_type
expires_in
access_token: "eyJraWQiOiI5NWE0MTU3Mi1iNDYxLTQ0NDctYjZkNy00MTg2ZWY0NTE1OTciLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJiZW4iLCJhdWQiOiJjbGllbnQiLCJuYmYiOjE3MjkxNTMxMzQsInNjb3BlIjpbInVzZXIucmVhZCIsIm9wZW5pZCIsIm9mZmxpbmVfYWNjZXNzIl0sImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODA4MCIsImV4cCI6MTcyOTE1MzQzNCwiaWF0IjoxNzI5MTUzMTM0LCJqdGkiOiI4MTIzZjI5Ni0zNTE5LTQwOTgtYWU2NS1hN2FmMDhhMGE0NTIifQ.Y-FGu2CvwC3j3_w2QfF4UMDN8GekXdhGH2F_KVxaCxlJgx5tlcf-XTsN6396R5SZr4qGOGs3eeBi5CL6nJPIcfk92uju1N1KgzsbsHpIcWZZANO2QRbBaCIXn0mO2nxHOWR8N77R5m_ST2bhXOP8vLmM68Q1I3-NzOEkQM9X8mSi8ve3JBOHGVjD1pyyyinxLtNpFdnJVVexnnmDHRBOpEaivqBi3mSWN6lfLovOTqUsAVVKPtMjuaxHFFmvfeSHp328w-JuGTsVd4Irisc2UF44bZ2fRG0vSTVWFVODemvanwkfurJ-8GhPbnvnsxhCDhw-UQ-iLkwFXcOmjhAD6Q"
​
expires_in: 299
​
id_token: "eyJraWQiOiI5NWE0MTU3Mi1iNDYxLTQ0NDctYjZkNy00MTg2ZWY0NTE1OTciLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJiZW4iLCJhdWQiOiJjbGllbnQiLCJhenAiOiJjbGllbnQiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE3MjkxNTMxMzMsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODA4MCIsImV4cCI6MTcyOTE1NDkzNCwiaWF0IjoxNzI5MTUzMTM0LCJqdGkiOiIxZjVlNzI4NC01ZjcyLTQxZmEtYWE4MS1kOTkwMGZjYjg1YmEiLCJzaWQiOiJMVUpCYlU1OWgxa290NGRsWmxadFJOZk96dE5QaEFOQWdQbWw0a2RLdWlNIn0.VqqlS1J1zLL79PVvvKujJOMDIKJkZQtzgspLYDZlM7FXZk2q02xFYrUE1X2YIg_5aAR2KDYspHlcpXarnxr6CQPNmjDdzqdYBsoehnXYJYkpw9tdmqy3qCkkywtaRrTwNxryFgAyJ6wl2bf_2nZpny2WIItTa2YFsahpZ3tTc6ezka4Nd5_aWQnlgl2fcRhNY_HPyLSDpoXtjlYX-IUNIr9ghoMPCU5koDzHQ1tUIbcZQevoJx84RXinjfIJJmIosBgdrGun0Z847OeE0Fw3YmNN5gC8CBT-8Rab5Irmsz5msF2P3ixMNBK9uilVhfhSbEzMTuA_rXnEhz4zq7zXiA"
​
scope: "user.read openid offline_access"
​
token_type: "Bearer"

There isn't any refresh_token, but by guides there should be this Token comes with the rest.
So I can't get an fresh access_token after the 300 seconds. And refresh the Browser all 5 minutes is no option.
Maybe anyone run into the same Problem and solve it and could Help me please?
I tried follows the offical Guide, watch YouTube and ask AI.
I include the  offline_access scope and the refresh_token grant-type into the application.properties.
spring.application.name=authorizationserver
server.port=8080

spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.registration.client-id=client
#spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.registration.client-secret={bcrypt}$2a$12$qew6z2l8LLQQeTRxqZekHOlT0jPtyrosuHtskyQBZiFOUaxXAgpIC
#spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.registration.client-authentication-methods=client_secret_basic
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.registration.client-authentication-methods=none
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.registration.authorization-grant-types=authorization_code,refresh_token
#spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.registration.redirect-uris=http://127.0.0.1:8082/login/oauth2/code/spring
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.registration.redirect-uris=http://127.0.0.1:5173/callback

# not working wether with or without client.client-1
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.token.refresh-token.enabled=true

spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.registration.scopes=user.read,user.write,openid,offline_access
spring.security.oauth2.authorizationserver.client.client-1.require-authorization-consent=true
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

It seems that the Problem is not very common, since I can't find any solution.

Edited the Topic: there aren't refresh token for public pkce clients.

It looks like you are setting up the application for OAuth but I don't see any issuer information. The issuer of the actual token would be what generates the refresh token. Spring just facilitates the keeping tracking of the refresh token and getting a new one. What you are looking for you will have to look at the token issuer documentation whether it be Github, Google, Azure... If you put the issuer name and configs as well that might help
If you look here in the documentation for spring security, it sets up a client to make the rest call to get the refresh token when needed
It looks like you are setting up the application for OAuth but I don't see any issuer information. The issuer of the actual token would be what generates the refresh token. Spring just facilitates the keeping tracking of the refresh token and getting a new one. What you are looking for you will have to look at the token issuer documentation whether it be Github, Google, Azure... If you put the issuer name and configs as well that might help.
If you look here in the documentation for spring security, it sets up a client to make the rest call to get the refresh token when needed docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/…

Hey, thank you for your answer!
The Issuer is in the application.properties of mine ResourceServer. Also the AuthServer - how seen in my Question - is the Issuer. I need to be the Provider for the OAuth 2.0. Followed is the Properties of mine ResourceServer:
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwks-set-uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/jwks
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080 and as Client I need to use an JS written Client.
